# Is there addon to make weight painting easier?

Tags: add-on, weight-painting

Good day. For the last 3 days I'm trying to weight paint my mesh and I still can't achieve good result. I've tried to use automatic weights - result is awful; I've tried to use auto normalize option after that - result is still awful; I've tried to create all weights by myself, but result is still awful in "bendable" areas:
[image]

I've tried to adjust result with sculpting, but it's breaking at the moment I'm trying to change character's pose. So, is there add-on that can help me to get a good result? Maybe something that can give more accurate result of automatic weights or anything else?

Comment: I know, from experience, that weight painting can be very frustrating when you're starting out.  I also know that the problems can be overcome.  If you want to share your rig + mesh + current weights at blenderartists.org, on the support/rigging and animation subsection, either I or someone else will be happy to work with you to help you learn what we know.

Comment: @Nathan thank you very much for your proposition, but I would prefer to make this work by myself. I just need a right direction, so, maybe, you can share some techniques here?

Comment: Sorry, no, this just isn't the right place for dialogue, and I think that learning from others demands some.

Comment: @Nathan it's okay, I'll use your advice if I won't find any solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Automatic weights are not perfect but usually, it should give you a good result to work with. Are you sure your mesh is OK? Flipped normals can mess up the weights for example.

Comment: @Blunder mesh is ok. Could be a problem if mesh have too little polygons? My mesh has only 8k polygons.

Comment: 8k polygons should be fine. Have you checked the status bar if there is a yellow message when you do automatic weights? Sometimes it fails and the calculation is aborted. Then the result is indeed awful. Automatic weights don't like intersecting mesh, duplicated vertices, and flipped normals. Loose meshes/multiple parts can also be problematic. Is the shirt a separate object or is it part of the character? Have you tried to separate it and parent it individually to the armature?

Comment: @Blunder yes, I've tried all of this, and every time I've got a bad result. I think I've found good solution so I've posted it as answer. But thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 5 days of attempts, I think I've found the best solution at that moment:

1. You need to scale mesh to make it bigger; bigger the mesh - bigger your chances to get good result.
2. After that - select body mesh, select clothes mesh, use `Object` -> `Link/Transfer Data` -> `Transfer Mesh Data` -> `Vertex` and select `All Layers` option in pop up window. With this you'll transfer all vertex groups from body to clothes.
3. Make rig parent of clothes mesh with `Empty Groups` option.

In that case I've got much more accurate weights, but there are still problems:

1. You'll get a lot of empty groups you don't need (I don't know how it will affect performance or occupied disk space) - for example, your character have tail, but you're trying to attach hat. Obviously, you don't need legs, hands, tail and other unrelated groups.
2. It's still need corrections.
3. If you have bad topology, it won't help you at all.
4. Maybe, something else I haven't found out yet.

I won't accept it as answer, because I'm sure there are the ways how to improve result, but I hope this will help people, who will run into the same problem.